# use groovy to activate remote ssh command with parameters

Tags: groovy, ssh

I am trying to activate a command on a remote server using a groovy script.
I already copied my ssh key to the remote server it worked.

```
ssh root@remote_server '/usr/local/bin/activate.pl'
```

when I tried to add parameters to the remote script I got failures:

```
ssh root@remote_server '/usr/local/bin/activate.pl android linux'
```

The errros are: `No such file or directory`.
Since I know the script is there and it worked before adding the parameters I guess the problem is adding the parameters.

when I activate the remote shell from the shell without the groovy the remote script works. How can I pass them to the remote script with groovy?
thanks

Comment: How are you running it? As a process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was running it as Jenkins user.

I found out that it is not possible to pass parameters to a remote script with groovy.
I created a local script that executes the ssh command and I activating the local script from Jenkins groovy